# How to open postgresql heap file

Tags: postgresql, relational-database, internals

I want to check how files, where PostgreSQL stores data from tables, are stored, for educational purposes. How can I do it?

I tried open it with notepad, but structure is corupt [database heap file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1xmh.png). "How should I open this file so that it is structured in a normal page view as:

```
 * +----------------+---------------------------------+
 * | PageHeaderData | linp1 linp2 linp3 ...           |
 * +-----------+----+---------------------------------+
 * | ... linpN |                                      |
 * +-----------+--------------------------------------+
 * |           ^ pd_lower                             |
 * |                                                  |
 * |             v pd_upper                           |
 * +-------------+------------------------------------+
 * |             | tupleN ...                         |
 * +-------------+------------------+-----------------+
 * |       ... tuple3 tuple2 tuple1 | "special space" |
 * +--------------------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: You can use the [pageinpsect](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pageinspect.html) extension. [Example](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/whats-in-an-xmax/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These files are binary files, not text files. That image is just a conceptual drawing. You'd need a hex editor to look at the data, but if you want to see them presented in human readable form, you should use the functions in the [pageinspect](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pageinspect.html) extension, in particular the `heap_page_items()` and `heap_page_item_attrs()` functions.